# Handle spaces in argparse input

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, user-input, argparse, spaces

Using python and argparse, the user could input a file name with -d as the flag.

```
parser.add_argument("-d", "--dmp", default=None)
```

However, this failed when the path included spaces. E.g.

```
-d C:\SMTHNG\Name with spaces\MORE\file.csv
```

NOTE: the spaces would cause an error (flag only takes in 'C:SMTHNG\Name' as input).

```
error: unrecognized arguments: with spaces\MORE\file.csv
```

Took me longer than it should have to find the solution to this problem...
(did not find a Q&A for it so I'm making my own post)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Simple solution:
argparse considers a space filled string as a single argument if it is encapsulated by quotation marks.

This input worked and "solved" the problem:

```
-d "C:\SMTHNG\Name with spaces\MORE\file.csv"
```

NOTICE: argument has "" around it.

Comment: As we usually read around here... feel free to accept your answer :D

Comment: This isn't about argparse; this is how shells parse arguments on most systems (and how programs fake shell-style-parsing on the systems that don't have real shells). By the time you get to the `argparse` module, your original version is already 4 separate arguments, and argparse can't do anything about that.

Comment: Quotation doesn't help in my case, I still get error: unrecognized arguments:

Comment: @Shaman, just throwing a guess out there -- if you copy-pasted the arguments, they might be the wrong unicode. “ is different than ". Other than that, more input from you might help. Does a print(argv) work?

Comment: @ofer.sheffer, in my case the arguments are generated, and all things happen in linux on server side, so no copy paste.

Comment: This did not work for me either.

ARGS="--datasourceFile \"../datasources/CI-CD Test Cube.smodel\""
echo $ARGS
then run

result:
--datasourceFile "../datasources/CI-CD Test Cube.smodel"
error: unrecognized arguments: Test Cube.smodel"

Comment: you probably forgot to pass $ARGS with quotes:
yourpythonscript "$ARGS"

Comment: Your solution is a miracle, it saved my week.

Answer (score 64):

For those who can't parse arguments and still get "error: unrecognized arguments:" I found a workaround:

```
parser.add_argument('-d', '--dmp', nargs='+', ...)
opts = parser.parse_args()
```

and then when you want to use it just do

```
' '.join(opts.dmp)
```

Comment: What if I have a string like : ma'am which has an apostrophe(') in the middle?

Comment: So to be honest I dont  even recall writing this comment. But I think this answer is better than the accepted one because it doesn't assume anything about the shell. the accepted answer isn't about argparse - its about shell. and it appears to not work for every kind of shell out there (as noted in the comments). plus, this answer outvoted the accepted one...

Comment: Passing double quotes around file path with spaces threw the same error in Windows. This workaround worked like charm.

Comment: If such an optional argument is specified before the positional arguments on the command line (which is a POSIX guideline) then the optional argument will consume all the positional arguments immediately following it.

Comment: This is just a workaround, not a definitive answer, for example if the string contains multiple consecutive characters (e.g. `ex  ample`), this method will not work.

Answer (score 12):

Bumped into this problem today too.

```
-d "foo bar"
```

didn't help. I had to add the equal sign

```
-d="foo bar"
```

and then it did work.

Comment: python 3.5.1 on RHEL6

Comment: This did not work for me either. my param looks like: 

ARGS="--datasourceFile=\"../datasources/CI-CD Test Cube.smodel\"" which echod looks like: 

--datasourceFile="../datasources/CI-CD Test Cube.smodel"  and I get error: unrecognized arguments: Test Cube.smodel"

Answer (score 3):

After some experiments (python 2.7 Win10) I found out that the golden rule is to put quotes ("") around arguments which contain spaces and do **NOT** put if there are no spaces in argument. Even if you are passing a string/path. Also putting a single quotes ('') is a bad idea, at least for Windows.

Small example:
python script.py --path ....\Some_Folder\ --string "Here goes a string"

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake, when forwarding bash script arguments, is to forget double quotes.
for example writting this:

```
ARGS="C:\SMTHNG\Name with spaces\MORE\file.csv"
mypythonscript  -d $ARGS
```

while it should be

```
ARGS="C:\SMTHNG\Name with spaces\MORE\file.csv"
mypythonscript -d "$ARGS"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 important points here (from my perspective):

1. You do not want to replace all the spaces in the argument input.
2. You want to use `argparse` interface.

My best aproax would be to use an `argparse.Action` with the function `strip` for the string:

```py
import argparse

class StripArgument(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values.strip())

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prog=f"your program", description=__doc__,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    epilog="See '<command> --help' to read about a specific sub-command.")
parser.add_argument(
    "-n", "--variable-name", type=str, default='vx', action=StripArgument,
    help="Variable name inside something (default: %(default)s)")
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to surround your path with quotes such as:

```
python programname.py -path "c:\My path with spaces"
```

In the argument parse you get a list with one element. You then have to read it like:

```
path = args.path[0]
```