# Python argparse adds extra space before an argument

Tags: python, command-line, arguments

I found that argparse adds an extra space before an argument. Based on the example code below

```
def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prog='sample',
    description='bla bla',
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--search', dest='pattern', required=True,
    help='search path pattern (e.g. /dir1/dir2/*.ext)')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.pattern[0] == ' ':
        print "One space is added to the argument"
    return args
```

and testing in interactive shell as:

```
import sys
sys.argv = ['', '-s /Users/user/Desktop/test']
execfile('test.py')
```

Providing the argument as `sys.argv = ['', '-s=/Users/user/Desktop/test']` does not cause such an addition (inspiring from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36376287/2101864).

Is it a documented behavior or do I miss something? Because it is typical that a regular user provide argument adding a space between argument tag and value.

Comment: Thank you @aneroid for your detailed clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you directly execute `test.py`, the extra space won't occur. That happens in the interactive shell because of what you're setting `sys.argv` to before executing `test.py`.

```
sys.argv = ['', '-s /Users/user/Desktop/test']
```

But when running the script from the terminal and checking `sys.argv`, you get:

```
['test.py', '-s', '/Users/user/Desktop/test']
```

It also ignores multiple spaces between `-s` and the value when running from terminal.

The shell/terminal already provides each parameter separately to the script (and Python puts them into a list). So the 2nd param is only `-s` and not `-s /Users/user/Desktop/test`. *Doing `sys.argv = ['', '-s', '/Users/user/Desktop/test']` in the interactive shell gives the right result.*

What argparse *probably* does is scan each arg in `sys.argv` and look for all argument name patterns, `-s` or `--search`. Once found, everything after that is the argument value. The `=` in `-s=/Users/user/Desktop/test` is standard `arg=value` notation (more so in the past), so it interprets that as the delimiter between an argument and its value.