# Python taking extra space in command line arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I have the following code portion in python and suppose we execute this python file with a input file input.txt as the first command line argument.

```
import os
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1],"r") as input:
```

Suppose the name of the python file is file.py and input.txt is the argument to this, so the command is as follows,

```
>>file.py input.txt
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hdutta\Desktop\file.py", line 3, in <module>
with open(sys.argv[1],"r") as input:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' input.txt'
```

Looks like it is taking an extra space at the first argument. Why is it so? Am I missing something. This was working before. But I have a new system now and I am facing this issue.

I got some clue in the link -- [Python argparse adds extra space before an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927190/python-argparse-adds-extra-space-before-an-argument)

But I am unable to modify `sys.argv =` if there is any way to do that.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Hmm weird

But you could do:

```
sys.argv[1].lstrip().strip() # Will remove any spaces to left / right of the string.
```

Comment: You don't need `lstrip`. Just `strip` will work fine

Comment: I can do that for this file.py I have added, but impossible to implement for some 3rd paty python file I am using as the basic problem with picking up the command line arguments

Comment: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/12/14/problem-passing-arguments-to-python-scripts-on-windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673657/detecting-calling-python-script-from-windows-dll-when-using-ctypes

Comment: Thanks. I think the issue was I was setting HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command: with `"%*"` at the end. When remove the `""`, the issue is resolved